# Efficient SQL query to find overlap between lists

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a MySQL table order_items (idorder, iditem, amount) that contains items that people ordered from a web shop. I want to find orders similar to an order X by finding other orders with similar items in similar amounts.

Here is my current approach:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
           SUM(GREATEST(1, LEAST(cown.amount, cother.amount))) hits,
           cother.`idorder`
           FROM order_items cown
           LEFT JOIN order_items cother ON (
               cother.`idorder` != 1
               AND cown.iditem = cother.iditem
           )
           WHERE cown.`idorder` = 1 AND cother.idorder IS NOT NULL
           GROUP BY cother.idorder ASC
           ORDER BY hits DESC
```

This selects all items from a given order and left joins them with items from other orders. Then I group by the other order ID and sum up the amount of overlap between them.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a recommendation engine. That would be tricky to implement in plain sql  and not sure how reliable. For starters have a look into the [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) project.

There is a nice example with Mahout and MySQL which you can try for yourself available on github: https://github.com/jasebell/RecommenderDemo and it looks like the thing you want.

Comment: This does look interesting, however it seems like it might be a bit of overkill for my purposes. I would also need to run this in PHP.

Comment: Then maybe this will help: http://api.shephertz.com/cloudapidocs/guide/0.8.1.1/php/recommendation_api.html